# misinterpreted png images in safari on mac

Tags: macos, safari, png

I've created a png file with Autocad's rendering tool and published it on a website. The problem is that it does not show in safari on mac. It displays correctly on Firefox installed on the same machine and on windows. I tried to figure that out and when I was inspecting the img element I found a message in the safari console saying something like: 
"Element interpreted as a document, but send with a image/png MIME type". I've translated that from polish so the original english message can be a little bit different. 
The problem occurs in Safari 4.0.1 on OS X 10.5.7. 
Here is the link to the image causing problems -
http://budujemyzop.files.wordpress.com/2009/07/biuro.png 
By the way the image when saved on the desktop displays correctly as a desktop icon and when previewed in finder's preview tool. When opened in the preview program by doubleclicking on the desktop icon it shows up for a fraction of a second and than disappears leaving a gray background.

Answer (score 0):

There is something corrupt about that image.  Safari gives me the message

> pngResource interpreted as document
>   but transferred with MIME type
>   image/png.

But if I open it in Photoshop and re-save it, I get one that works in Safari and Preview.